# Compass with sass install

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I uninstalled all sass versions on my mac because I read where compass is not compatible with 3.3.0 sass. I did a new install of compass using

```
sudo gem install compass
```

After success install my terminal window says.

- Fetching: sass-3.2.18.gem (100%)
- Successfully installed sass-3.2.18
- Fetching: compass-0.12.4.gem (100%)
- Successfully installed compass-0.12.4
- Parsing documentation for compass-0.12.4
- Installing ri documentation for compass-0.12.4
- Parsing documentation for sass-3.2.18
- Installing ri documentation for sass-3.2.18
- 2 gems installed

When I try to run command compass version
I get this.

> /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:22:in
>   `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)

Anyone know why I'm getting this is it because I installed it using sudo. 
Is there anyway to just install it into each project. Or not have to run sudo all the time before it.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all gems installed and you will be able to retrieve a working version by running the installation again (your PATH seems weird as the last ruby version is not the 2.0.0...).

Comment: Don't think the Ruby version is relevant since Sass works with 1.9.3+